# Upload ffmpeg to Azure Function Environment PATH [Python]

Tags: python, ffmpeg, azure-functions, filepath

I am doing the audio extraction project. Audioread library is used in my python script. Audioread required FFMPEG to be existed in linux /usr/bin. If the FFMPEG is existed in /usr/bin, the code  `audioread.audio_open(XXX.m4a)` can run without error, if not, it will output  `NoBackendError`

I can run my code successfully in my local linux system. However, the code will output `NoBackendError` in Azure Function. My guess is the ffmpeg is not deployed to the /usr/bin, but is deployed in /home/site/wwwroot. My python code cannot find ffmpeg in PATH.

I have tried to use `os.popen('mv /home/site/wwwroot/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg')` in my python script to move ffmpeg to PATH, but it doesnt work. I think the reason should be I did not add sudo, but I dont know the password of Azure Function Linux platform.

Please give me some help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think the reason should be I did not add sudo, but I dont know the password of Azure Function Linux platform.

Users can run commands with elevated privileges on a Linux virtual machine using the **sudo** command. However, the experience may vary depending on how the system was provisioned.

1.***SSH key and password or password only*** - the virtual machine was provisioned with either a certificate (.CER file) as well as a password, or just a user name and password. In this case **sudo** will prompt for the **user's password** before executing the command.

2.***SSH key only*** - the virtual machine was provisioned with a certificate (.cer or .pem file), but no password. In this case **sudo** **will not prompt for the user's password** before executing the command.

You can refer the following link :  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-root-privileges/

---

I followed the official tutorial  [***Create your first Python function in Azure***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python)  to create a  `HttpTrigger`  Function for Python, and tried different ways to make  `ffmpeg`  works in Azure Functions, it works for me.

These are my steps:

1. Install  ***Azure Functions Core Tools***  on my local Windows machine to create a project named  **MyFunctionProj**  and a function named **HttpTrigger**.
2. Before uploading `ffmpeg`  with deployment, checked the OS platform architecture of my instance of Azure Functions on Azure via change the official sample code with the code below.

   ```py
   # add these codes
   import platform, os
   .....

   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()}")
   ```

   Its result is  `Hello krishna! ('64bit', '')`  in browser.
3. Then I put the  `ffmpeg`  AMD64 static binary file downloaded from  https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  into my  **MyFunctionProj**  and change my code below to check the file path, and to command  `func azure functionapp publish MyFunctionProj`  to publish to Azure.

   ```py
   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()} {os.listdir()} {os.listdir('HttpTrigger')}")
   ```

Output:

`Hello krishna! ('64bit', '') ['in.mp4', 'ffmpeg', 'host.json', 'requirements.txt', 'ffmpeg.exe', '.python_packages', 'HttpTrigger'] ['in.mp4', '__pycache__', 'sample.dat', 'host.json', 'function.json', '__init__.py']`  in browser as same as these in my  `MyFunctionProj`

4. I found everything in **MyFunctionProj** folder will be uploaded to Azure and call  `os.listdir()`  to show the file list of **MyFunctionProj**, so the current path in Python is the same as  **MyFunctionProj**  locally. Then I tried to invoke  `ffmpeg`  in my local Windows environment via the code below.

   ```py
   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()} {os.listdir()} {os.listdir('HttpTrigger')} {os.path.exists('in.mp4')} {os.popen('ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 out.mp4').read()} {os.path.exists('out.mp4')} {os.popen('del out.mp4').read()}")
   ```

   It works to output the file `out.mp4` via command  `ffmpeg.exe -i in.mp4 out.mp4`, then considering for reproduce it to command  `del out.mp4`.
5. Try to make it works for Linux environment on Azure Function, I change the commands with  `./ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp4`  and  `rm out.mp4`. But it didn't work on Azure Function. It may be caused by missing the execute permission of  `ffmpeg`  Linux binary file while uploading from Windows. So I checked via command  `ls -l ffmpeg`  and  `chmod u+x ffmpeg`  before invoke it.

   ```py
   def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
       if name:
           return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}! {platform.architecture()} {os.listdir()}  {os.listdir('HttpTrigger')} {os.popen('ls -l ffmpeg').read()} {os.popen('chmod u+x ffmpeg').read()} {os.popen('ls -l ffmpeg').read()} {os.path.exists('in.mp4')} {os.popen('./ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp4').read()} {os.path.exists('out.mp4')} {os.popen('rm out.mp4').read()}")
   ```

   It works now, the result is like below I formatted it pretty.

   ```py
   Hello krishna! // Official sample output
   ('64bit', '') // the Linux platform architecture of Azure Functions for Python 
   ['in.mp4', 'ffmpeg', 'host.json', 'requirements.txt', 'ffmpeg.exe', '.python_packages', 'HttpTrigger']  // file list of MyFunctionProj
   ['in.mp4', '__pycache__', 'sample.dat', 'host.json', 'function.json', '__init__.py'] // file list of HttpTrigger
   -r--r--r-- 1 root root 69563752 Nov 10  2021 ffmpeg // before chmod u+x
   -rwxr--r-- 1 root root 69563752 Nov 10  2021 ffmpeg // after chmod u+x
   True  // in.mp4 exists
   True // out.mp4 exists before delete it using `rm`
   ```

Comment: I have tried the above, http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-root-privileges/, it is just run the ffmpeg command line tool, the python library still cannot detect the ffmpeg and output ```NoBackendError```. I need to add ffmpeg to the PATH of Azure Function, if not my local python file cannot run on the Azure Function.

Comment: @user14834847, Please check this - 
After download and installing the [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/), make sure you can start `ffmpeg`  from the command line (type  `ffmpeg -h`). You will probably need to add the path to the install folder (eg  `c:\ffmpeg\bin`) to the Windows path. Finally, make sure to restart your IDE. Visual Studio Code probably won't recognise the new path until after a reset.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is the point, is there any method that can add the path to the folder of ffmpeg or move ffmpeg to system PATH of AZURE Serverless Function. My code and ffmpeg both can work well locally.

Comment: @user14834847 - The ffmpeg dependencies will be in root path of our project like `<project_root>/ffmpeg_lib` directory. Please check this [Mcrosoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/bring-dependency-to-functions?pivots=programming-language-python) on how to add your `ffmpeg path` into your project folder of your azure function and how to access it.

Comment: I dont know why it doesnt work for me. I finally edit the source file of the audioread library ```audio_open``` function to make it can call ffmpeg even the ffmpeg is not in the environmet PATH. Anyway, thank you for your help!